# Make a vertical dynamic list of posts in alphabetically order and in columns

Tags: posts, css, order

I have a page that lists all the posts from a given category of an custom post type dynamically. I do this with a plugin that list posts and a shortcod and with css i created 9 columns where they are sorted horizontal after letter.  Instead I would like to have this in a vertical alphabetically dynamic ordered lists, preferably sorted under a letter. like this: http://skatematic.com/channels

Since css doesn't seem to cut it with this, I'm not sure where to start. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply create a custom query with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You just need to make sure if you are using a custom taxonomy or the build-in category. For reference, see: [Is There a Difference Between Taxonomies and Categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545)

Here is an example for custom taxonomies (this can also be used for build-in categories, just change `'taxonomy' => 'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',` to `'taxonomy' => 'category',`):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'THE_SLUG_FROM_MY_TERM',
        ),
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

For a single term, you can also work directly with the query vars, so you can change your `$args` to something like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY'    => 'THE_SLUG_FROM_MY_TERM',
);
```

If you have a built-in category, change your `$args` to the following

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'cat'    => 'THE_ID_OF_YOUR_CATEGORY',
);
```

For more useful parameters and the use there of, go and check out `WP_Query` in the codex

Comment: Im probably the stupidest guy in the world, but my whole question came ut totaly wrong. I meant to say I have the list in 9 columns and i wanted it sorted alphabetically and vertical, not horizontal which is the case now.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a styling issue then, making your question off topic. This should be better asked then on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Um ive been told css and vertically alphabetically columns is impossible. I did find this, so maybe paired with your wp_query could be something: http://code.nxil.com/2013/07/23/column-list-alphabetical-order-query/

Comment: Can't say on the top of my head now, but my query should be more than enough, don't see the need for so many queries. My php is not up to scratch, by I would think that if you add the query results to an array, and then sort that array accordingly, you should be able to achieve what you want

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147933/31545) and [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149547/31545)

Comment: Oh thanks for that. i managed to get an ouputed list if my custom taxonomy with the letter infront, thats great! Thats step one for me.. the second in is to sort it in columns.. This is the result so far: http://skateflix.se/test-2/

Comment: Well if it was an styling issue, it would be solved.I have one "faulty" code where styling doesn't work due to the code, and one where styling works, but lack some php. Sorry for the lack of credit, just been back and forth whit this issue so much that I dont even now what is what anymore. Wouldn't gotten this far without your help though!