# Custom taxonomy archive page problem

Tags: posts, loop, customization

My website is built on custom post types, that I have organized with different custom taxonomies.
The menu buttons are the taxonomies archive pages (red, blue, green), so that when you click on the term 'red' of the custom taxonomy 'socks' (for example) you get all the articles that correspond to red socks.
Now then, the problem is I only have one page (called taxonomy-socks.php) that deals with the custom taxonomy term archive page and I would like to set a little presentation of the red socks, the blue socks, the green socks with pictures and css style... on each archive page, but I have no idea how to acheive this !
The best choice I guess would be to make the description in an article and then display each article on each custom taxonomy term archive page... But how ?
This is the code of my page taxonomy-socks.php :

```
<div class="main-content">
 <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">
     <h1><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
      <?php 
      if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
      $i++;?>
         <div class="portfolio<?php if ( ($i%3) == 0 ) { echo ' last'; } elseif ( ($i%2) == 0 ) { echo ' two-last'; } elseif ( ($i%4) == 0 ) { echo ' very-large'; } ?>" data-thematique="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('thematique')); ?>" data-activite="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('activite')); ?>" data-niveau="<?php echo implode(', ', get_field('niveau')); ?>">
                                <div class="project-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                                <div class="project-info">
                                <span class="portfolio-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">NIVEAU :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('niveau'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">THÉMATIQUE :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('thematique'); ?></span></span>
                                    <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">ACTIVITÉ :</span> <span class="white"><?php the_field('activite'); ?></span></span>
                                      <span class="portfolio-act"><span class="light">Lieu : </span><span class="white"><?php echo the_field('lieu1'); ?></span></span></div><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="button portfolio-button">EN SAVOIR PLUS</a>
                            </div>

      <?php
      endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?></div> 

      </div></div>
```

Thanks for your help... I hope it's clear enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many choices here, and it is all up to you what you want to achieve and how you want to achieve it.

My idea would be to use the templates available to avoid a lot of `if else` conditional statement. The [Template Hiearchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) makes provision for templates for terms, `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}.php`, so you could create a tempate for each term. So for red, you can create `taxonomy-socks-red.php`.

I know this is going to get quite overwhelming, but so is any other method I think

**EDIT 1**

Here is something else you can try. *I don't have time to test this right now as we are celebrating "Nasionale Braaidag" :-)*

- First, register a new post type, call it something like 'descriptions'. You can leave the defaults as is so that this [post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) is not publicly queryable. Please see attached link to all arguments and parameters you can use

  ```
  function codex_custom_init() {
      $args = array(
        'label'  => 'Descriptions'
      );
      register_post_type( 'descriptions', $args );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
  ```
- You can now write posts that will be shown on top of your loop in your `taxonomy-socks.php`. Start of with the title of the specific term. If your post is targeting the term `red`, make your title something like `Red - Great color socks to wear to the Rammstein concert'
- Using the following code from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149547/31545) by @G.M. you can search your custom posts by the title name and return the post if it matches the name of your term. This goes into your functions.php

  ```
  // require PHP 5.3+
  add_action( 'posts_where', function( $where, $query ) {
    if ( isset( $query->query['name__in'] ) && is_array( $query->query['name__in'] ) ) { 
      global $wpdb;
      $names = array_filter( array_map( function( $name ) use( $wpdb ) {
          $sane = sanitize_title( $name );
          return ! empty( $sane ) ? $wpdb->prepare( '%s', $sane ) : NULL;
     }, $query->query['name__in'] ) );
      if ( ! empty( $names ) ) {
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name IN (" . implode( ',', $names ) . ")";
      }
    }
    return $where;
  }, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
  ```
- You are already getting the current term name, so no need for extra code here. You are going to return `$term->name` to the new `name__in` parameter in a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). This query will go just above your main loop

  ```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'descriptions',
    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
    'name__in'        => $term->name
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
             //Show what you need to show
      }

  } 
  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ```

**EDIT 2**

OK, I have tested everything, and it seems that the code from @G.M. is not fit for this job. I have however tested with the following code I found a while ago from @birgire in one of his [answers here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136758/31545). This is better suited for the job

So, you need to make the changes accordingly, here is how

- You are still going to register your custom post type `descriptions` (and note, it cannot be `description`) and you are still going to write your special posts as in **EDIT 1** with the title as explained
- What is going to change is how we are going to query the posts. First of all, we are going to create a new `name__like` parameter and extend the `WP_Query` class. Here is the code. You can also link to the answer from @birgire. *This goes into your functions.php*

  ```
  class WPSE_Query extends WP_Query // thanks @birgire https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136758/31545
  {       
      public function __construct( $args = array() )
      {
          add_filter( 'posts_where', array( $this, 'posts_where' ), 10, 2 );
          parent::__construct( $args );
      }
      public function posts_where( $where, $qry )
      {       
          remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );    
          $name__like = $qry->get( 'name__like' ); 
          if( ! empty( $name__like )  )
          {
              $where .= " AND ";
              $where .= $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts;
              $where .= ".post_name LIKE '";
              $where .= esc_sql( like_escape( $name__like ) );
              $where .= "%' ";            
          }   
          return $where;
      }
  }
  ```
- Now we can query the posts, but we are not going to use the original `WP_Query` method, but its new extended class, `WPSE_Query`. So your new custom query will look like this

  ```
  $args = array(
    'post_type'       => 'descriptions',
    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
    'name__like'        => $term->name
  );
  $the_query = new WPSE_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
             //REMEMBER TO CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR LOOP ELEMENTS LIKE 
             the_title();
      }

  } 
  /* Restore original Post Data */
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ```

I hope this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: One last question, from what I can understand is this, you will update or add these special posts from time to time, am I correct? I just want to get a general idea of where I must go for a solution

Comment: Absolutely, I just need a presentation of the items people are gonna find on the specific page they're on. The only update I might have will be when I have new items (like orange socks), I'm gonna have to create another term "orange", and create a new 'description' post type for this new archive page.
Otherwise I can give you the link to the site I'm building ...

Comment: Please see my update in **EDIT 2**

Comment: Oh my there must be something I'm doing wrong, and I can't figure out what...
Like I said earlier on : is it a problem if some of my terms have more than one word in them ? Like "Navy Blue" ? And for the title of that description, is "Navy Blue, great socks for a NIN concert" a good title?

Comment: Is it working for other single word terms, like red

Comment: YES !!! But.... most of my terms have multiple words in them :( ... so sorry to make this awkward...

Comment: Lets try ID's. Change  `'name__in' => $term->name` to `'name__in' => $term->term_id` and then instead of the term name in your post title, use the term id

Comment: Doesn't work with the ID ...

Comment: Don't change post titles, I think it has something to do with 2 separate words in `name__in` parameter. Quickly try `'name__in' => $term->slug`

Comment: Reset your post title back to term name, if that does not work, try using slugs in post titles

Comment: I really need some sleep, this project has been driving me crazy, but I know now that the problem is nearly solved, thanks to you. Thank you ever so much for your help, I have made major improvements to my site since you've helped me !
I will surely get back to you tomorrow.. Thanks again.

Comment: I have just seen your comment and tried your solution and it looks like it's working !
I'll test it more deeply tomorrow.
YOU RULE PIETER !! :)))

Comment: Have a good night rest. Sometimes all one need is a little sleep, and after that, good rock music, and you should be good to continue :-). Enjoy

Comment: Ok just tested everything  : I approve this method !
IT WORKS. Thank you so much Pieter, you've made my day, my week ! =)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy your weekend :-)