# Query posts by specific word on title

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts

Is it possible to query posts by a specific word on title?

Example:

I have 3 posts inside my blog and only two have the word **car** on the title.

1. She wants a ride on my truck
2. My **car** is super fast
3. Her **car** is yellow

If this is possible, query should return only posts 2 and 3.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have some MySQL knowledge, you'd achieve this. your search returns 3 posts because the first one contains the word 'car' in the content. See this blog post http://sam.elegance-style.com/2015/08/08/wordpress/search-find-posts-pages-containing-keywords-content-wordpress/ replace `WHERE post_content LIKE '%$query%'` with `WHERE post_title LIKE '%$query%'`

Comment: Here are two great answers which will solve your issue: 1.) [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136758/31545) by birgire. 2.) [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149547/31545) by gmazzap

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136714/wp-query-get-posts-by-category-and-similar-name-like/136758#136758).

The full credit of the answer to my question goes for the author of the answer [birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire).

All I had to do was slightly change is plugin "Support for post name like in WP_Query" turning it into a function like this:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_like_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function title_like_posts_where(  $where, $q) {
if( $name__like = $q->get( '_name__like' ) )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_name LIKE %s ",
        str_replace( 
            array( '**', '*' ), 
            array( '*',  '%' ),  
            mb_strtolower( $wpdb->esc_like( $name__like ) ) 
        )
    );
}
return $where;
}
```

A special thanks to [Pieter Goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) for pointing my out to the solution.

Comment: You should post your code as you hve said you have changed it, otherwise your question is just a duplicate ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks, again! By the way, do you know how can I multiple words in the title instead of just one? Example: How can I query `'_name__like'   => 'Her car*'`

Comment: Unfortunately not, my SQL is really bad. Would be great if @birgire can see the post and comment ;-)